# Joining two dataframes using vaex

Tags: python, vaex

I am trying to join two data frames that were all imported by vaex. I think this should be simple but I am having challenges with the `vaex expressions`. Here's what I did:

```
vx_neighbors.join(vx_neighbours_df, on=['Neighbour', 'Year', 'day'])
```

and I got the error:

```
c:\python-3.8.2\lib\site-packages\vaex\join.py in join(df, other, on, left_on, right_on, lprefix, rprefix, lsuffix, rsuffix, how, allow_duplication, prime_growth, cardinality_other, inplace)
    145     left = left if inplace else left.copy()
    146 
--> 147     on = _ensure_string_from_expression(on)
    148     left_on = _ensure_string_from_expression(left_on)
    149     right_on = _ensure_string_from_expression(right_on)

c:\python-3.8.2\lib\site-packages\vaex\utils.py in _ensure_string_from_expression(expression)
    770         return expression.expression
    771     else:
--> 772         raise ValueError('%r is not of string or Expression type, but %r' % (expression, type(expression)))
    773 
    774 

ValueError: ['Neighbour', 'Year', 'day'] is not of string or Expression type, but <class 'list'>
```

How can I convert the list to a vaex expression?

Comment: I believe that at this time joining on multiple keys is simply not supported. Perhaps for this it is better to open an issue on their github to show interest in the feature.

Answer (score 1):

As @Joco mentioned, you cannot officially join on many columns in Vaex. However, you can unofficially join by creating a join-key column.

```
import vaex

df1 = vaex.from_arrays(
    Neighbor=["bob", "alice", "jared"],
    Year=[2020, 2021, 2020],
    day=["M", "T", "T"]
)

df2 = vaex.from_arrays(
    Neighbor=["bob", "alice", "jared"],
    Year=[2021, 2021, 2020],
    day=["M", "T", "W"]
)

for d in [df1, df2]:
    d["join_key"] = d["Neighbor"] + "-" + d["Year"].astype(str) + "-" + d["day"]

joined = df1.join(df2, on="join_key", rsuffix="_R")
display(joined)
```

Notice that I'm casting the non-string columns to string, that's required.